# How do I retrieve basic info with Owl Carousel 2

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm using Owl Carousel 2 jquery slider and I'm trying to retrieve some basic info, in particular I want to display the number of the current slide in the paragraph tags above the slider with the class of "currentSlide".

Here is my markup:

```
<p class="currentSlide"></p>

<div id="slider" class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item"><h3>Slider 1</h3></div>
  <div class="item"><h3>Slider 2</h3></div>
  <div class="item"><h3>Slider 3</h3></div>
  <div class="item"><h3>Slider 4</h3></div>
  <div class="item"><h3>Slider 5</h3></div>
  <div class="item"><h3>Slider 6</h3></div>
</div>
```

And here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      items: 3,
      center : true,
      loop : true,
      //info: ??Function??
  });
});
</script>
```

In the documentation it says this about adding the "info" option:

> info
>
> Type: Function
>
> Default: false
>
> Callback to retrieve basic information (current item/pages/widths). Info function second parameter is Owl DOM object reference.

I need some help with this "info" function as I'm a total newbie to jquery.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The events object passed to callbacks has all the info you need:
[(see: Docs/Events/Data)](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-events.html#data)

Thus, you simply need to add a callback on some event ... `translated.owl.carousel` may be work best in your situation.

```
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
owl.owlCarousel();

owl.on('translated.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $('.currentSlide').text( event.item.index );
});
```

... and you may want to add an `initialized.owl.carousel` callback as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is taken from here:
http://www.jq22.com/demo/OwlCarousel2/demos/info.html

use "info: getInfo", following function lists all parameters, so just choose one:

```
function getInfo(i){
  var owlInfo = i,prop,value,name;
  for(prop in owlInfo){
    if(owlInfo.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      value = owlInfo[prop];
      name = prop;
      $('.'+name).text(value);
    }
  }
}
```